# req.isAuthenticated never changes in NodeJS/Passport App

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I am building an app with NodeJS and am using PassportJS for user authentication.  I'm using `req.isAuthenticated` as an argument in `res.render(/some-url function(req, res) {pass in object here})` to change the layout of a page depending on whether or not someone's logged in.

Right now my page ALWAYS renders as being logged in, even if I'm just starting up the app!

Here's my code for Passport:

**Authentication Code:**

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.email);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas", function(e, db){
  if (e) {return next(e);}
  var col = db.collection("users");
  col.find({"email": id}, function(err, user){
      done(err, {"email": id});
      });
    });
  });

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: "email",
  passwordField: "password"
},
function(username, password, done) {
  mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas", function(e, db) {
  if (e) {return next(e);}
  var col = db.collection("users");
  col.find({"email": username, "password": password}, function(err, user){
    if (err) { return done(err);}
    if(!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: "Please check your log in   
    credentials." });
    }
    return done(null, {email: username, password: password});
      });
    });
  }));

router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/',     
  failureRedirect:'/login',failureFlash: false})
);

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/login');
});
```

Here is the relevant portion of my express configuration:

**APP.JS:**

```
app.use(cookieParser());
// Express Session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//initialize passport for app
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// make mongodb available to the application
app.use((req, res, next) => {
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas', (e, db) => {
  if (e) return next(e);
  req.db = db;
  next();
  });
});
```

I have tried playing around with some different configurations for `app.use(session{})` but this has not made an impact.

I render pages in the following way:

```
router.get(/page-location function(req, res) {
    res.render('view', {
        loggedIn: req.isAuthenticated
    }
});
```

And then in my view do

```
if (loggedIn) {
   //show this stuff
}
if (!loggedIn) {
  //show that stuff
}
```

It's always displaying as `loggedIn`, even after I log out (which successfully redirects upon completion), but for some reason `req.isAuthenticated` keeps showing up as `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `findOne` instead of `find` while querying in `LocalStrategy`. Since `find` will always return an Array. So `!user` will always be false.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: "email",
  passwordField: "password"
},
function(username, password, done) {
  mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas", function(e, db) {
  if (e) {return next(e);}
  var col = db.collection("users");
  col.findOne({"email": username, "password": password}, function(err, user){
    if (err) { return done(err);}
    if(!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: "Please check your log in   
    credentials." });
    }
    return done(null, {email: username, password: password});
      });
    });
  }));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, however, this change does not do the trick.  And FWIW I've queried using my original code and have returned an actual user w/ `req.user` with my original code when I query.  The problem is that once I make a request to `/login` it's like I'm stuck in some sort of loop where `req.isAuthenticated` never changes.

Comment: I'll also add that `req.user` turns up as `undefined` when I start up my app, so the specifics of `req.user` don't seem to be determining the hiccup.